# JSF: h:outputText; how to show a dash when the value is empty string?

Tags: jsf, el

I'm using h:outputText tags to display readonly data.  Ex:

```
<h:outputText value="Phone Number:" />
<h:outputText value="#{userHandler.user.phoneNumber}" />
```

When "phoneNumber" is an empty string or a null, I want to display a dash "-" as the value.

Is there any easy way to do this maybe with expression language or something?

BTW, I thought about adding methods to the User class like getPhoneNumberDisplayText() that could do the check internally, but I since it's a view issue, I'd rather keep the code in the JSF page.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
<h:outputText value="#{userHandler.user.phoneNumber != null 
    ? userHandler.user.phoneNumber : '-'}" />
```

Or, you could make a new `outputText`:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{userHandler.user.phoneNumber == null}" value="-" />
```

Comment: Just use `empty`. Covers both `null` and empty string. `#{empty foo.property ? '-' : foo.property}` or other way, `#{not empty foo.property ? foo.property : '-'}`.

Comment: @BalusC this doesn't work for `set` method `Illegal Syntax for Set Operation`. is there solution for that?