# Avoiding null point exception in el in JSF

Tags: jsf, el

I am developing a JSF application with JPA(EclipseLink 2.0) and Primefaces. 
I want to know is there any way to avoid null point exception when el calls a property of a null object. I have described the situation.
I have Bill class. There may be no or more BillItem objects with a Bill objects. Each BillItem object have Objects like Make, Country, Manufacturer, etc objects. I am displaying several properties of a bill within a single JSF file like this.

```
"#{billControlled.bill.billItem.modal.name}"
```

But if a bill is not selected, or when there are no bill items for a selected bill, the properties accessing in the el are null. I can avoid this by creating new objects for every bill, for example, new make for a new bill item, etc or by creating new properties in the controller itself for all the properties. But that is a very long way and feel like rudimentory.

Is there any good practice to avoid this null point exception in el in JSF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution. Before every el, I can check null.

[JSF: h:outputText; how to show a dash when the value is empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787730/jsf-houtputtext-how-to-show-a-dash-when-the-value-is-empty-string)

```
<h:outputText value="#{userHandler.user.phoneNumber != null 
? userHandler.user.phoneNumber : '-'}" />
```

Or

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{userHandler.user.phoneNumber ne null}"  value="#{userHandler.user.phoneNumber}" />
```

Comment: I did this and still got NPE. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Solution is checking for null (and you can also check for empty) and use with render attribute.

Empty can work well with Collections (check for both empty and null), and also with null.

For example:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{not empty myBean.myData}"  value="..." />
```